# Chain from Queueable

Tags: queueable-apex

Is it possible to make a chain of execution with Queueable?
My task after running the first Queueable is to get a token (callout) and only when it is available (in Custom MetaData) to run the next Queueable to update the user data in a new call out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation explains this, relevant detail and link below.

> Chaining jobs: You can chain one job to another job by starting a
> second job from a running job. Chaining jobs is useful if your process
> depends on another process to have run first.

> Chaining Jobs To run a job after some other processing is done first
> by another job, you can chain queueable jobs. To chain a job to
> another job, submit the second job from the execute() method of your
> queueable class. You can add only one job from an executing job, which
> means that only one child job can exist for each parent job. For
> example, if you have a second class called SecondJob that implements
> the Queueable interface, you can add this class to the queue in the
> execute() method as follows:

```
public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        // Your processing logic here       

        // Chain this job to next job by submitting the next job
        System.enqueueJob(new SecondJob());
    }
}
```

> You can’t chain queueable jobs in an Apex test. Doing so results in an
> error. To avoid getting an error, you can check if Apex is running in
> test context by calling Test.isRunningTest() before chaining jobs.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

Comment: Looks like that I can not update Custom Meta Data and run chain Queueable in the same Queueable. Or I am missing something?